# How do you Expand All/Collapse All in lightning:accordion

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, refresh, accordion

I'm trying to Expand All/Hide All in **lightning:accordion** Lightning aura component.

```
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.pboW.listPb}" var="pbW">

            <lightning:accordionSection name="{'S' + !pbW.index}" label="{!pbW.pb.Name}">
                     -- complex content goes here--
            </lightning:accordionSection>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:accordion>
```

Saw below [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleAccordionMultiple) in Documentation and I tried to set activeSectionName assuming it might help.
[image: Expand multiple sections]

My Js controller code for Expand/Collapse All:

```
switchExpandAll: function(component, event, helper) {
    var viewAll = (component.get('v.viewAll')==true);
    viewAll = (!viewAll);
    component.set("v.viewAll", viewAll);

    var expandedSections = [];

    if(viewAll){
        var pboW = component.get("v.pboW");
        for(var idx = 0; idx < pboW.listPb.length; idx++){
            expandedSections.push('S'+pboW.listPb[idx].index);
        }
    }
    console.log('expandedSections '+expandedSections);
    component.set('v.activeSections',expandedSections);
},
```

But it seems not refreshing accordingly. Really appreciate any thoughts, suggestions to achieve Expand All/Collapse All sections.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can show or hide all sections using `activeSectionName` attribute. Also `allowMultipleSectionsOpen` should be set to `true`.
Sample code:

COMPONENT:

```
<aura:attribute name="activeSections" type="List" default="[]" />
<aura:attribute name="activeSectionsMessage" type="String" default="" />

<lightning:button label="Show" onclick="{!c.ShowHideAll}" />

<p>{! v.activeSectionsMessage }</p>

<lightning:accordion allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true"
                     activeSectionName="{! v.activeSections }" >
    <lightning:accordionSection name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
        Accordion Body A
    </lightning:accordionSection>
    <lightning:accordionSection name="B" label="Accordion Title B">
        Accordion Body B
    </lightning:accordionSection>
    <lightning:accordionSection name="C" label="Accordion Title C">
        Accordion Body C
    </lightning:accordionSection>
</lightning:accordion>
```

CONTROLLER.js:

```
ShowHideAll: function (component, event) {
    let activeSections = component.get("v.activeSections");
    if (activeSections.length === 0) {
        component.set("v.activeSections",["A","B","C"]);
    } else {
        component.set("v.activeSections",[]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas I could figure out the issue with my code.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue.

It seems when I used expression `name="{'S' + !pbW.index}"` in `<lightning:accordionSection name="{'S' + !pbW.index}" label="{!pbW.pb.Name}">` it did not work because I had used incorrect expression mistakenly.

Fixed below,

e.g.

```
<lightning:accordionSection name="{! 'S' + pbW.index}" label="{!pbW.pb.Name}">
```

Comment: Merge fields are in the form of `{! ... }`. The correct version would be `{!'S'+pbW.index}`.

Comment: @sfdcfox Oh too bad, Didn't notice that until now! Thank you very much!